# Object Just Black in Shading Tab?

Tags: modeling

I'm new to Blender, and I'm running it on a low-level Windows machine. Intel Core 2 Quad 3.2ghz processor, 12 gb of ram, and an ATI Radeon HD 4300 graphics card.

I'm really not looking to do any heavy lifting in blender, just some small projects for class. When I make any shape, even a simple UV sphere and click over to the shading tab, my object is all black. I can't figure out why.

I've run this on my Macbook as well and got the same problem.

Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

Comment: Unsupported graphics card (you can recognize it from two black spheres right down in viewport.  Blender use card for viewing Material mode and for Eevee Render engine. But you can still use Solid mode or Render mode for Cycles.

Comment: In addition to what @vklidu said: [Blender 2.8x needs at least OpenGL 3.3 to run](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/). Radeon HD 4300 only supports OpenGL 3.1. It's actually amazing that Blender 2.8x starts at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely an issue with the shading mode. There are several ways to preview objects in Blender: wireframe, solid, shaded, textured, etc. Try clicking around on these:

### [image]

Also, in your screenshot, you're in "World" editor mode (in the Shader editor). Make sure your world background isn't pure black/set to 0. If you don't have any lights in the scene, this is the only thing lighting it, and if it's set to 0 or pure black then there is no lighting at all, hence everything is black.